# PowerShell change proxy addresses in Active Directory with Set-ADUser

Tags: powershell, proxy, active-directory

I have a small code where I don't know if it should work, because i'm at work at the moment and the proxy addresses are only created in production, and I'm afraid that the code wont work when I use it in production.

So the code logic is : 
-getting the proxy addresses
-if the proxy address starts with `"smtp:"`, it will change to `"smtp:d_"`

For example, `"smtp:test@gmail.com"` would change to `"smtp:d_test@gmail.com"`

Here's my code :

```
#### proxy adresses
$Obj_CompteMPOP3 = Get-ADUser $login -Properties proxyaddresses -server $serverSource
$NewProxyAddresses = @() #new array of proxy addresses

$Proxies = $Obj_CompteMPOP3.proxyaddresses #get the proxy addresses of the LDAP object
foreach ($Proxy in $Proxies) {
    if ($Proxy.Substring(0, 5) -like 'smtp:*') #if the address starts with smtp:
    {
        $ProxyPrefixe = $Proxy.Substring(0, 5)
        $NewProxy = "$ProxyPrefixe$D_$($proxy.Substring(5))" #make the new proxy address with the format "smtp:" -> "smtp:d_"
        $MPOP3_NewProxyAddresses += $NewProxy #add the value to the new array of proxy addresses

        Set-ADUser $login -Replace @{ProxyAddresses = $MPOP3_NewProxyAddresses} -Server $serverSource -Credential $CredActivateSIRHMPOP3 #set the new addresses with the new array
    }

}
```

The line which i'm not sure at all is the `set-aduser`. Can it be used? Seems logical to me considering the `get-aduser` gives you back an array

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: How should anybody know whether it will work in your production server without knowing anything about your servers? To just validate that the powershell script works it should be fine to change the proxy address in your local machine. Just open a shell, execute the commands and see what happens

Comment: the three first lines of the code work, it will give me back the proxy addresses. I just want to know if the set-aduser would work, I'm not sure about setting new proxy addresses via an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set ad-user will work as a command but you need to add the value as an array.

From my experience, when we changed our mail server I had to export all the user addresses and add them to the proxy address attribute with the primary having capital SMTP.

What I did was:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true) -and (sAMAccountType -ne 805306370) -and (cn -ne "Administrator")} -SearchBase "CN=,DC=,DC=,DC=" -Properties proxyAddresses |
Select Name, GivenName, Surname, Enabled, SamAccountName, Title,  `
@{L='ProxyAddress_1';E={$_.proxyaddresses[0]}}, `
@{L='ProxyAddress_2';E={$_.ProxyAddresses[1]}}, `
@{L='ProxyAddress_3';E={$_.ProxyAddresses[2]}}, `
@{L='ProxyAddress_4';E={$_.ProxyAddresses[3]}}, `
@{L='ProxyAddress_5';E={$_.ProxyAddresses[4]}}, `
@{L='ProxyAddress_6';E={$_.ProxyAddresses[5]}}, `

Export-Csv -Path "Your path\Your filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter "|"
```

I am using | as a delimiter so I don't have to care if there is a , or a ; in the data I export.
Then changed the addresses with the replace command and set the users properties.

```
$Temp = Import-Csv -Path "Your path\Your filename.csv" -Encoding Default -Delimiter '|'
ForEach ($User in $Temp) {
Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -Clear proxyaddresses
Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $User.ProxyAddress_1}
Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $User.ProxyAddress_2}
Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $User.ProxyAddress_3}
Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $User.ProxyAddress_4}
Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -Add @{proxyAddresses = $User.ProxyAddress_5}
}
```

So the Set-ADUser command is working but you have to put the -Add and set that value to the multivalued attribute.

Hope this helps you.

Edit: Also you can see the -Clear command before adding new values because if you have too many mail aliases in one user you may find yourself in a difficult situation.

Answer (score 1):

After several tries I got this working in order to replace wrong characters in the proxuAddresses array attribute:

```
$pa = Get-ADObject "$idistinguishedname" -Properties proxyAddresses | select proxyAddresses
$pa | foreach {If ($iVALUE -ceq $pa[0]){Set-ADObject "$idistinguishedname" -replace @{proxyAddresses=$iUPDATE}}}
```

$iVALUE and $iUPDATE came as input from a CSV file that I exported and carefully edited after running IdFix tool vs my AD in order to fix inconsistencies. IdFix tool should have done this but it errored out and had to code a PS script to finish what the tool couldn't.